# Error: code 1091 Invalid Code Signing Entitlements 'com.apple.security.app-sandbox'

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect, entitlements, xcrun

I'm trying to upload an app built with Unity on MacOs to AppStoreConnect, and  I get this error when validating the .pkg file with xcrun altool --validate-app

```
 Error: code 1091 (App Store operation failed. Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. 
 Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on macOS.
 Specifically, key 'com.apple.security.app-sandbox'
```

The entitlement file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I tried removing the key from the entitlements file, or setting the value to false. then re-signing, rebuilding the package, re-validating the app but then I get this:

```
Error: code 1091 (App Store operation failed. App sandbox not enabled.
The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement 
with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list.
```